# Mysql Stored Procedure + Update Query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

The issue is with the mysql procedure. I want to run an update query inside mysql procedure. I have created the procedure and called it without any error. But the problem is the update query inside the procedure is not getting executed.

```
delimiter $$
create procedure update_member_status(IN new_mem_id int,IN mem_count int)
begin

declare tot_ref_count,mem_ref_id int default 0;

select ref_id into mem_ref_id
from ccf_user
where user_id=new_mem_id;

select ref_count into tot_ref_count 
from ccf_user
where user_id=mem_ref_id;

if tot_ref_count = mem_count then
update ccf_user 
set status='permanent'
where user_id=mem_ref_id;
else
update ccf_user 
set status='*****'
where user_id=mem_ref_id;
end if;

end
$$
```

Then I have call the procedure:-
    call update_member_status(25,6)

I want the update query inside the procedure to execute

Answer (score 0):

I would start from rewriting this procedure into a single SQL statement:

```
UPDATE ccf_user c1, ccf_user c2
   SET c1.status = 
       CASE WHEN c1.ref_count = @mem_count 
            THEN 'permament' ELSE '*****' END
WHERE c1.user_id = c2.ref_id
      AND c2.user_id = @new_mem_id
;
```

then analyze if it gives expected results, for example using this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2310b/1